# Питонщик или питонист?

Tags: выбор-слов

Программистов, активно пользующихся языком Python часто называют "питонщиками" или "питонистами". Какой из этих вариантов правильный? Или правильны оба?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147839/discussion-on-question-by----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более распространенный вариант - питонист.